# Tesseract training character size and frequency

Tags: tesseract

The documentation of Tesseract says:

> Make sure there are a minimum number of samples of each character. 10
>   is good, but 5 is OK for rare characters.
>
> There should be more samples of the more frequent characters - at
>   least 20.

1. I assume the last sentence means: at least 20 samples of more frequent characters would be OK. But what will be a good frequency?

Also:

> Tesseract works best on images which have a DPI of at least 300 dpi,
>   so it may be beneficial to resize images. For more information see the
>   FAQ.

2. Why does Tesseract work best on 300 DPI? Isn't DPI just an setting telling on what scale an image is being printed? Why DPI and not just a minimum height in pixels?
3. Also, what would be a good height of an character in pixels?